# Speed up the decompression of a tar.gz

Tags: java

I'm trying to unpack a tar.gz archive with lots of files and folders inside. I'm using Apache commons compress v1.21

The code is this:

```
public void decompress(File archive, File destination) {
        File tar = new File(destination, archive.getName().substring(0, archive.getName().length() - 3));

        try (FileInputStream isArchive = new FileInputStream(archive);
             GZIPInputStream gzip = new GZIPInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(isArchive));
             OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(tar);
             InputStream in = new FileInputStream(tar);
             TarArchiveInputStream is = (TarArchiveInputStream) new ArchiveStreamFactory().createArchiveInputStream("tar", in)
        ) {
            IOUtils.copy(gzip, out);
            TarArchiveEntry entry;
            while ((entry = is.getNextTarEntry()) != null) {
                File file = new File(destination, entry.getName());
                file.getParentFile().mkdirs();
                Files.write(file.toPath(), is.readAllBytes());
            }
        } catch (IOException | ArchiveException e) {
            Logger.log(LogLevel.ERROR, e, "An error occurred during a decompression", "Archive: " + archive.getName());
            return;
        }
        tar.delete();
    }
```

Is there any way to speed up the process? Can multiple files be decompressed in parallel?

Comment: No. Because the stream is compressed. You can't randomly access bytes, you have to decompress serially.

Comment: Is there a library better than Apache commons compress to speed up decompressions?

Comment: The ***decompression*** is `GZIPInputStream`. And it's reasonably fast for what it is. There are certainly **faster** options, **but** they aren't compatible with your current format. [lz4](https://engineering.fb.com/2016/08/31/core-data/smaller-and-faster-data-compression-with-zstandard/) should be about 9x faster. Of course, first you need your tar compressed with lz4.

Comment: So I have to archive everything in tar and compress/decompress it with lz4?

Comment: You don't "have to" do anything. But if you want it to be faster, then yes; that is one way to make it faster.